# TTreeView - Change Expand and Collapse Image?

Tags: delphi, treeview

Is it possible using the standard TTreeView to change the Expand and Collapse Image?

I don't mean Node images, I mean the little arrows next to Nodes that have children, like so:

[image]

Ideally I would like the arrows to show as + and - Symbols, like the Delphi component structure tree:

[image]

If it is possible to change this, how would I go about doing it?

**Working Demo based on David's Answer**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, Themes, uxTheme;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TMyTreeView = class(TTreeView)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyTreeView }

procedure TMyTreeView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  if ThemeServices.Enabled and CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
    SetWindowTheme(Handle, nil, nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyTree: TMyTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  MyTree := TMyTreeView.Create(nil);
  with MyTree do
  begin
    Parent  := Self;
    Height  := 100;
    Width   := 100;
    Left    := 30;
    Top     := 30;

    Node := Items.Add(nil, 'Item');
    Items.AddChild(Node, 'Item');
    Node := Items.AddChild(Node, 'Item');
    Items.AddChild(Node, 'Item');
  end;
end;

end.
```

The Result:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tree views in post-Vista Windows have two alternative themes. The theme that you are wanting to avoid is known as the explorer theme. You want to use the standard theme. A control has to opt-in to get the explorer theme. It does so via the [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  API. The VCL tree view control calls this to opt-in. It does so at the end of its `CreateWnd` method.

You can revert to the standard theme by undoing the change like this:

```
type
  TMyTreeView = class(TTreeView)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;

procedure TMyTreeView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  if StyleServices.Enabled and TOSVersion.Check(6) and StyleServices.IsSystemStyle then
    SetWindowTheme(Handle, nil, nil);
end;
```

This code is written for XE2. If you have an earlier Delphi then I think you want it like this:

```
  if ThemeServices.Enabled and CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
    SetWindowTheme(Handle, nil, nil);
```

Comment: You can just call the function from form OnCreate to test it out. The CreateWnd approach is what you need to "do it right".

Comment: works great thanks, I will edit the top post with how I implemented your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I addition to Davids answer. Put the following code in some extra unit and add it in the uses after the ComCtrls unit. That way you can use the standard TTreeView and change the theme whenever you like. Or register it in your own package if you like.

```
type
  TTreeView = class(ComCtrls.TTreeView)
  private
    procedure SetExplorerTheme(const Value: Boolean);
  public
    property ExplorerTheme: Boolean write SetExplorerTheme;
  end;

procedure TTreeView.SetExplorerTheme(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled and CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
    if Value then
      SetWindowTheme(Handle, 'Explorer', nil)
    else
      SetWindowTheme(Handle, nil, nil);
end;
```

In never Delphi versions you could also use a class helper to avoid the extra inheritance.

Comment: It's important to do this in CreateWnd because the window handle can be recreated.

Comment: This is not a class helper. Class helpers are specific code construct (type THelper = class helper for THelpedClass or some such, I am not sure of the exact syntax here, as I don't use them that much). What you are doing in your example is generally known as an `interceptor class`.

Comment: @Marjan Correct. And what's more, if you are going to use an interceptor then `CreateWnd` is readily available for override.

Comment: In retrospect perhaps not, but the fact that you moved your remark down to "avoid confusion" says a lot... :-)